# How do I add a horizontal 1px white line below the button in html

Tags: html, css

How can i display a line below button on hover in html5,css3

[image: button below line]

Comment: share some code with us - show code of the button!

Comment: `:hover`, `border-bottom:`.

Comment: i am using bootstrap3

Answer (score 2):

If you change the default button css class it'll change all your bootstrap buttons.

```
.btn-default:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

You can easily make your own css button class. Then apply it to a few buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in css, with classes.  If your navigation buttons have a class of 'nav-button', you can do something like this:

```
.nav-button:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.nav-button:active {
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(255, 217, 0)!important;
}
.nav-button:visited {
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(255, 217, 0)!important;
}
.nav-button:hover {
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(255, 217, 0)!important;
}
```

Comment: Can you add explanation to the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer